# Is there a way to fill tiny holes leftover when joining meshes together?

Tags: mesh, groups

[image: fill holes when joining]

I merged/joined some planes when transforming them with the polytool. I saw that this 2 tiny holes were left. Is there a way to fill them or get rid of them?

edit:
Here is the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dXx1yfb26n3zDAgd4fUslDRNZp3yxl_c/view?usp=sharing

I must confess I'm a beginner in Blender, so expect funky stuff.

Comment: Can you tab into edit mode, take a screenshot and add it to your question? I am asking you to do this so I can take a look at the geometry of the mesh. Sharing your file will also be very helpful.

Comment: I agree with @Ribbit12 that a look at the geometry in _Edit Mode_ would be helpful, because the way the mesh looks is essential for answering this question.

Comment: @Ribbit12 Hi, I added the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do with the object, having this shape as one big N-gon is perfectly fine and there is no need for complex rebuilding. First get rid of the *Bevel* and *Build* modifiers on the object. Then do the following:

1. In *Edit Mode*, select the sphere and the ring and press <kbd>H</kbd> to hide them.

[image: rebuild 1 - hide rest]

2. Now select all visible geometry by pressing <kbd>A</kbd>, then choose <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge* > *By Distance* to get rid of double vertices.

[image: rebuild 2 - remove double vertices]

3. Deselect all with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, then select the central vertical shape by hovering the mouse over one corner vertex and pressing <kbd>L</kbd>. Then delete it with <kbd>X</kbd> > *Delete* > *Vertices*.

[image: rebuild 3 - remove center]

4. Now enable the *Snap* tool (the magnet symbol at the top) with *Snapping* > *Edge* (the dropdown menu next to the magnet). Select one top corner vertex of the trapezoid shape in the center, double-tap <kbd>G</kbd> to use *Edge Slide* and move the vertex towards the edge of the wing close to it until an orange circle shows you that it's snapped to the edge. Do the same with the other side. Left vertex to left edge and right vertex to right edge.

[image: rebuild 4 - snapping vertices]

5. Now do the same accordingly for the large wings. Select one of the inner vertices and double-tap <kbd>G</kbd> to edge slide it down until it snaps on the corner vertex of the trapezoid, then repeat it for the other side.

[image: rebuild 5 - snapping the large parts]

6. Again, you can now select all vertices with <kbd>A</kbd> and merge all doubles by pressing <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge* > *By Distance*. After that, select the four vertices around the empty space in the center, then press <kbd>F</kbd> to create a face between them.

[image: rebuild 6 - fill space]

That's it, you could now select all faces and hit <kbd>F</kbd> to join them to one single N-gon or leave it like that, whatever you need. To unhide the invisible geometry, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. I would then recommend to select all vertices with <kbd>A</kbd> again and once more choose <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge* > *By Distance* because there are more double vertices in this geometry as well. Of course you could do this with all vertices right at the beginning, I was just focusing on the central shape in my instructions.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed step by step!

Answer (score 1):

In this answer, I am going to guide you through GIFS to rebuild your mesh, so that it has good geometry. There are too many overlapping edges and your mesh is made up of several other disconnected objects. The geometry of a mesh is very important. We need to try to maintain a good geometry for texturing, UV unwrapping, adding modifiers etc.

**Final Result(without build modifier):**

[image]

**Final Result with build modifier:**

[image]

**STEP 1**

[image]

**STEP 2**

[image]

**STEP 3**

[image]

**Edited File:**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wERFUuV24M1OgDqgqKXYDXhGrkSzIZvj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks! I can just select one "solution", but I appreciate this too.

Comment: No problem,to be honest Gordon's solution was definitely better :)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is either:

Selecting the edges and pressing  <kbd>F</kbd> to make a face
or <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>F</kbd> if it fails (this will create triangles).

Merging them using *Mesh > Clean up > Merge by distance*. These are both not ideal solutions however as they can cause bad topology, especially if subdivided. If you mirrored it using the mirror modifier check your merging distance.

Comment: Apart from maybe creating bad topology, as I said in the comments it depends a lot on how the mesh actually looks like. If you take a look at this picture: https://pasteall.org/pic/16b110d9084846638dba509609fc020b the object on the left and right look absolutely the same in _Object Mode_ (top row), but the meshes are completely different in _Edit Mode_ (bottom row). It depends on how the object was created. With the object on the left, none of the solutions you've given will work. You can neither select edges and press F nor can you merge by distance.

Comment: As Gordon mentioned in the comments after taking a look at @dawns file this method can never work with his mesh.

Comment: I had no idea sorry, a blend file was not provided when I rambled

Comment: @Sven_ That's why we commented we need more information before we could give an answer ;)